# What is the purpose of exhausting Galio when he ults?

Tags: league-of-legends

In this game, Galio is repeatedly exhausted everytime he uses his ultimate ability.  However, Galio's ultimate roots him to one place.  What's the purpose of exhausting Galio when he uses his ult?

http://www.own3d.tv/clgame#/watch/529435

Answer (score 9, accepted):

exhausting also reduces attack and ability damage:

> Slows movement speed by 40% and reduces (auto/basic) attack damage by 70% and ability/item damage by 35%.

and if you have improved from talents it also reduces resists

> Improves Exhaust to also reduce the target's armor and magic
>   resistance by 10 for the duration.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Exhaust)

Comment: Ah!  I forgot about the damage debuff.  I thought maybe it was for the improved exhaust which also lowers armor/mr, but that didn't seem worth it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Toast you are right too "Runic Skin (Passive) Galio's passive allows him to deal more damage while becoming more resistant to enemy spells. Thus allowing Galio to be a tank and heavy magic dealer." Reducing the MR you also reduce the Damage from Galio

Comment: Although frankly, the damage from galio's ult is usually far less than the damage his team can inflict during the long AoE crowd control. If the Karthus in that game (who was the only one who had exhaust) could reach the enemy AD carry with exhaust, that would be the better choice to exhaust. The enemy AD carry was Kog'Maw, who has long attack range and extreme attack range with his bio arcane barrage activated. Likely the Karthus couldn't reach him to exhaust him.

Comment: They didn't seem to be having much trouble killing kog maw ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason regarding 35% damage reduction might be the after-the-fact justification for why people do this, but honestly it is more likely that it is a gut reaction to a fight-changing ability like Galio's Ultimate. They know that they want to do SOMETHING to stop him, and perhaps exhaust is all they have, so they throw it down. I cannot think of a situation where exhausting an ulting Galio would be more valuable than saving it for a more dangerous enemy champion.

Just my two cents.

Comment: I think that's a great point, but in the video I linked they're clearly exhausting Galio every time he ults (after the ult starts).  The commentor even mentions the strategy, which made me take notice.

Comment: I honestly don't know what that commentator is talking about when he says that "exhaust just crushes Galio." In a 1v1 confrontation exhaust will almost always get you the kill, but the CC from Galio's ult should be the main consideration, allowing his team to wreak havoc on the enemy. Unless there is something that I'm missing, I simply think this was poor play and poor commentating... Anyone have any further insight?

Comment: Blem's answer might be helpful.  I think 35% damage reduction is the big reason why.

Answer (score 1):

Well the purpose of using exhaust on Galio while he's channeling is that you will lover the amount of dmg he will do. With that in mind you're not aiming for movement speed because he mustn't move while channeling, the only goal is to make his ulti do less dmg than intended.

Answer (score -1):

I think the damage from Galio's ult is pretty negligible.  After all, Galio builds pretty tanky, and his ult damage is based on all the auto-attacks he receives, which isn't going to be that much for the short duration.  The game-changing ability of Galio's ult of course is the AoE CC that it does to the enemy team.  When combined with any other good AoE comp, you can completely devastate teamfights.

In short, I would say the team who exhausted Galio messed up or misclicked.  Exhaust is a defensive spell primarily as it can make champions who deal insane damage suddenly deal no damage.  They should be saved for Carries, primarily burst carries.

Answer (score -3):

Exhausting Galio during ult is a waste of a summoner ability. Galio ult is mainly for cc and aggro also brings team into one location for a bigger aoe damaging spell like Nunu's or Orina's and Syndra. I play Galio allot and I can tell u exhaust me all u want I still will not care cause my damage is low any ways I am basically a top that goes to support mode in team fights. So basically what u are doing is exhausting a support while his team wails the crap out of u for 2 sec.